# Making a string out of a string and an integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get this error when trying to take an integer and prepend "b" to it, converting it into a string:

```
  File "program.py", line 19, in getname
    name = "b" + num
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

That's related to this function:

```
num = random.randint(1,25)
name = "b" + num
```

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6380529/2071807) addresses why Python doesn't just cast the RHS of `+` to a `str` like Javascript does. It was kind of surprising to me but that answer explains it well.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
name = 'b' + str(num)
```

or

```
name = 'b%s' % num
```

Note that the second approach is deprecated in 3.x.

Comment: The % is deprecated in Python 3. Might want to remove that one.

Comment: @S.Lott I have to work on some systems using python <2.6, namely Ubuntu 8.04. I didn't realize .format wasn't available, and after developing the code on Python 2.6, having to go and change all the .format commands to % was a bit of a pain. So, actually, while I prefer .format, if you need compatibility with every version, % is still your best bet - it IS present in Python 3, while .format is not present in python 2.5 and below.

Comment: @S.Lott % is not deprecated in Python3. [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) clearly mentions that *The new system does not collide with any of the method names of the existing string formatting techniques, so both systems can co-exist until it comes time to deprecate the older system.*

Answer (score 11):

Python won't automatically convert types in the way that languages such as JavaScript or PHP do.

You have to convert it to a string, or use a formatting method.

```
name="b"+str(num)
```

or printf style formatting (this has been deprecated in python3)

```
name="b%s" % (num,)
```

or the new .format string method

```
name="b{0}".format(num)
```

Comment: The % is deprecated in Python 3.  Might want to remove that one.

Comment: I can't edit it now it seems, so noted here that % is deprecated. Also worth mentioning is that .format isn't available before Python 2.6.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.6 has [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) where you can directly put the variable names without the need to use `format`:

```
>>> num=12
>>> f"b{num}"
'b12'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, python doesn't having implicit int to string conversions.

try `str(num)` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "b{0:d}".format( num )
```