# WHY this happens with my lovely Python: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, string, int, type-coercion

First of all, I've searched around for Python issues regarding:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

There are many answers. But my question is not how to solve the above problem in Python.

My question is the WHY. Why Python, a very lovely language, chooses to behave in this way?

I know that Java does support this auto-coercion of int to String. Is there a technical rationale for not automatically coerce int to string in Python? 
Of course, explicit is better than implicit but from my experience this coercion is practically useful to programmers.

According to my experience, writing something like:

```
s = 'This file has ' + linenum
```

is quite common. It'd be really convenient to coerce int to string. For String to int, I don't see as much a need.

I've found Python a very elegant language. But the above problem occurs to me so repeatedly that I think I need to ask it here in StackOverflow. It really intrigues me.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380500/why-does-python-not-perform-type-conversion-when-concatenating-strings

Comment: Thanks BoppreH. The link is helpful. 

Another question is why doesn't Python support: String + int --> auto convert int to string?

Comment: The fact that Python doesn't do this is one of the reasons it's so lovely.