# How can I concatenate str and int objects?

Tags: python, string, operator-overloading, string-concatenation, string-conversion

If I try to do the following:

```
things = 5
print("You have " + things + " things.")
```

I get the following error in Python 3.x:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

... and a similar error in Python 2.x:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: FYI: There are now 11 answers deleted as duplicates. **All** of the methods pertaining to the question in the OP, are covered in the accepted answer. If you post an answer that's already covered, it will be deleted as a duplicate. There is no additional value for SO to keep multiple answers with the same solution. Instead, upvote existing answers.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380500 for the rationale behind why Python doesn't just convert the type implicitly.

Comment: **Most** questions that could be a duplicate of this one, should really just be deleted; they generally need more focus or have other significant problems (in particular, it isn't clear whether this or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-f-string-literal is a better target) and won't function as a good signpost.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772 for questions that *aren't already* trying to use `+` and just want a technique for interpolating a value into a string.

Comment: The body of this question is deliberately concise. Please use the comment feature to add comments.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The problem here is that the `+` operator has (at least) two different meanings in Python: for numeric types, it means "add the numbers together":

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
>>> 3.4 + 5.6
9.0
```

... and for sequence types, it means "concatenate the sequences":

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> 'abc' + 'def'
'abcdef'
```

As a rule, Python doesn't implicitly convert objects from one type to another<sup>1</sup> in order to make operations "make sense", because that would be confusing: for instance, you might think that `'3' + 5` should mean `'35'`, but someone else might think it should mean `8` or even `'8'`.

Similarly, Python won't let you concatenate two different types of sequence:

```
>>> [7, 8, 9] + 'ghi'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Because of this, you need to do the conversion explicitly, whether what you want is concatenation or addition:

```
>>> 'Total: ' + str(123)
'Total: 123'
>>> int('456') + 789
1245
```

However, **there is a better way**. Depending on which version of Python you use, there are three different kinds of string formatting available<sup>2</sup>, which not only allow you to avoid multiple `+` operations:

```
>>> things = 5
```

```
>>> 'You have %d things.' % things  # % interpolation
'You have 5 things.'
```

```
>>> 'You have {} things.'.format(things)  # str.format()
'You have 5 things.'
```

```
>>> f'You have {things} things.'  # f-string (since Python 3.6)
'You have 5 things.'
```

... but also allow you to control how values are displayed:

```
>>> value = 5
>>> sq_root = value ** 0.5
>>> sq_root
2.23606797749979
```

```
>>> 'The square root of %d is %.2f (roughly).' % (value, sq_root)
'The square root of 5 is 2.24 (roughly).'
```

```
>>> 'The square root of {v} is {sr:.2f} (roughly).'.format(v=value, sr=sq_root)
'The square root of 5 is 2.24 (roughly).'
```

```
>>> f'The square root of {value} is {sq_root:.2f} (roughly).'
'The square root of 5 is 2.24 (roughly).'
```

Whether you use [% interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), or [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) is up to you: % interpolation has been around the longest (and is familiar to people with a background in C), `str.format()` is often more powerful, and f-strings are more powerful still (but available only in Python 3.6 and later).

Another alternative is to use the fact that if you give `print` multiple positional arguments, it will join their string representations together using the `sep` keyword argument (which defaults to `' '`):

```
>>> things = 5
>>> print('you have', things, 'things.')
you have 5 things.
>>> print('you have', things, 'things.', sep=' ... ')
you have ... 5 ... things.
```

... but that's usually not as flexible as using Python's built-in string formatting abilities.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although it makes an exception for numeric types, where most people would agree on the 'right' thing to do:

```
>>> 1 + 2.3
3.3
>>> 4.5 + (5.6+7j)
(10.1+7j)
```

<sup>2</sup> Actually four, but [template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) are rarely used, and are somewhat awkward.

---

Other Resources:

- [Real Python: Splitting, Concatenating, and Joining Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-string-split-concatenate-join/#concatenating-with-the-operator)
- [Python.org: `string` - Common string operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)
- [python string concatenation with int site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20string%20concatenation%20with%20int%20site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=AOaemvJC8RSgXr4NApCMLYxLMHBSHV7RwA:1633282602287&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihw87q467zAhXPGDQIHcIhDqwQrQIoBHoECAgQBQ&biw=1920&bih=975&dpr=1)