# Python27 TypeError: unsupported operand for type(s) += 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Please help me understand what's happening here. My aim is to create a function that will read "input.txt" and return the min, max, and average for each line within the text document. The text within the document is as follows:

```
min:1,2,3,4,5,6
max:1,2,3,4,5,6
avg:1,2,3,4,5,6
```

My code looks like this:

```
import re

def process():

    file = open("input.txt", "r")

    for line in file:
        newL = re.findall("\d+", line)

    minimum = min(newL)
    maximum = max(newL)
    length = len(newL)
    numSum = sum(newL)

    print newL
    print minimum
    print maximum
    print length
    print numSum

    file.close()

process()
```

Everything prints out fine except for numSum, which gives the error mentioned in the heading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall` gives you back a list of strings, something like `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`. The implementation of `sum` is something like this:

```
def sum(xs):
    total = 0
    for x in xs:
        total += x
    return total
```

So at some point, it'll attempt to execute a line like `total = 0 + "foo"` and fall over, since Python doesn't know how to add an `int` to a `string`. The fact that you know all your strings actually contain `int`s is immaterial, since the expression `1+'1'` might sensibly evaluate to either `'11'` or `2`, and Python won't guess which.

As you read in each line, you should convert every string to an int. That ought to solve your problem

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus, indeed, I wanted a simpler example, though. Given that OP seems to be quite new and this may well be a homework problem, I didn't want to just hand out the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added a list comprehension to cast all the strings as integers and it worked. ' newL2 = [int(item) for item in newL] '

Comment: @Muzi, no worries. If this answer solved your problem, you may want to accept it with the green tick. You might also find it constructive to edit my answer to include your solution.