# how str() implement in python?

Tags: python, concatenation

## Definition of savings and result

```
savings = 100
result = 100 * 1.10 ** 7
```

## Fix the printout

```
print("I started with $" + savings+  " and now have $" + result+  " Awesome!")
```

## Definition of pi_string

```
pi_string = "3.1415926"
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is, could you be more specific?

Comment: have you tried running your code and seeing what error it gives?

Comment: You cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Comment: @olivier, close as "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: @wofwca Close as duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

You can either convert the `int`s into `str`s like this:

```py
print("I started with $" + str(savings)+  " and now have $" + str(result)+  " Awesome!")
```

or use a string formatting like this:

```py
print("I started with ${} and now have ${} Awesome!".format(savings, result))
```