# Unable to concatenate integer in my "print" statement

Tags: python

I am unable to place an integer inside my print statement alongside a string, and concatenate them together.

```python
pounds = input("Please type in your weight in pounds: ")

weight = int(pounds) * 0.45

print("You " + weight)
```

I thought that I would be able to put these together, why am I unable to?

Comment: `print("You " + str(weight))`

Comment: Find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to concat a string with an integer it's going to throw an error. You need to either cast the integer back into a string, or print it without concatenating the string

You can either

a) use commas in the print function instead of string concat

```
print("You",weight)
```

b) recast into string

```
print("You "+str(weight))
```

**Edit:**
Like some of the other answers pointed out, you can also

c) format it into the string.

```
print("You {}".format(weight))
```

Hope this helps! =)

Comment: Thanks so much! What exactly goes on with the first example (with the comma)? I guess it reads the "you" as a string but what about the weight?

Comment: `print` is a function.  `"You"` and `weight` are two arguments.  Try `print(1,2,3)`.  or `print(1, 2, 'astring')`.  Read up on `print`.  It's an important function.  In the bigger picture you want to learn `format` (and the older `%` style), and `str()` and `repr()` functions.

Comment: @Christopher Yep "you" will be read as a string, and weight will still be an integer, but by separating them  with commas in your print function, it lets Python know that you are only trying to print the two variables out and not trying to combine them with concatenation. =)

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't let you concatenate a string with a float. You can solve this using various methods:

Cast the float to string first:

```
print("You " + str(weight))
```

Passing `weight` as a parameter to the print function (Python 3):

```
print("You", weight)
```

Using various Python formatting methods:

```
# Option 1
print("You %s" % weight)
# Option 2 (newer)
print("You {0}".format(weight))
# Option 3, format strings (newest, Python 3.6)
print(f"You {weight}")
```

Answer (score 1):

`print("You %s" % weight)` or `print("You " + str(weight))`

Comment: Or `print("You {}".format(weight))`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use format strings like `print(f"You {weight}")`

Answer (score 0):

Python is dynamically typed but it is also strongly typed. This means you can concatenate two `str`s with the `+` or you can add two numeric values, but you cannot add a `str` and an `int`.

Try this if you'd like to print both values:

```
print("You", weight)
```

Rather than concatenating the two variables into a single string, it passes them to the `print` function as separate parameters.