# How to make Python speak

Tags: python-3.x, text, speech-recognition, uigesturerecognizer, gtts

I have seen a lot of examples in here but I haven't got what I wanted. All of the examples which I have seen make Python speak only what is typed.

Ex. `speaker.speak('What is your name?')`

But **instead** of making python speak **whatever is typed**, I want this:

```
a = 2+2
speaker.speak('Your answer is',a)
```

How to make it speak a calculated variable.
Here, it should speak Your answer is 4, but it's only speaking Your answer is.

Comment: `speaker.speak('Your ans is' + str(a))`

Comment: So you know how to make it say _any string_, right? If so you can simple format your string to include any variables you need

Comment: Ok will try @Asocia

Comment: For what? @Justlearnedit

Comment: It didn't worked. Any other try u want me to do? @Asocia

Comment: Ya that's what I am asking, how to do? @ForceBru

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects) help?

Comment: @freak What is the error you get?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the entire sentence to a variable. For example:

```
text_to_speak = "Your answer is " + str(a)
speaker.speak(text_to_speak)
```