# When do I need to add quotation marks around an integer in Python

Tags: python

I just learnt that there is no quotation for integer in Python, but why is it needed in this case:

```
character_name = "Tom"
age = "50"
print("There once was a man named " + character_name + ",")
print("he was " + age + " years old.")
```

Comment: You are casting the integer to a string to be able to print it, meaning `50` becomes `"50"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Comment: Precisely the case given in the above link. `+` is mathematical addition for numerical types, but concatenation for string types. Given that you want to join non-numeric strings, you'll need to convert the integer to a string first for python to understand what `+` should do

Comment: There's no integer in you statements, just string. "+" operator here just to concate strings, so you need to use str(age), not age if your age is integer.

Comment: do like this: `print(f"he was { age } years old.")` then you can leave it integer

Comment: when using `print` you can separate values with comma, example : `print("He was ", age, " years old.")`

Answer (score 3):

Using quotes to a digit, makes him become a `string` when it was an `int` (or `float`) so it changes its values, you cannot do numerical operation on it anymore.

What you may need is the string representation of a number when concatenating it with other strings, here you may do

```
print("he was " + str(age) + " years old.")
```

Or, let print do it, by giving several parameters, and each one will be given its string representation

```
print("he was", age, "years old.")
```

---

In resume, don't add quotes to a number when assigning it because it won't be a number anymore, handle it differently when you need but not as its beginning

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to do it if you use the `format()` method in Python 3, ie.:

```
character_name = "Tom"
age = 50
print("There once was a man named {}, he was {} years old.".format(character_name), age)
```

This is better in case you need to use the variable `age` in some equation later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

when you use 2 strings and a “+” you concate them but when you use 2 numbers and a “+” you summarize them so if you use one string and one number and a “+” it gives you an error so you convert your number to a string

Valid Example 1:
`age = 30 name = “John” new_string = name + str(age)`

Valid Example 2:
`age = “30” name = “John” new_string = age + name`

invalid Example:
`age = 30 name = “John” new_string = name + age #Throws an issue`