# why does this program giving me the error when i am using + in print() function and giving me the output when i am using ','

Tags: python

**Why this is working.**
Input `print(9, "ABC")`
Output `9 ABC`

**And This is not working and showing the error.**
Input `print(9 + "ABC")`
output
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Comment: Yes, it answered my question

Answer (score 0):

9 is an integer and "ABC" is a string, so it is impossible to add an integer and a string.

You can use it like that;

```
print(str(9) + " " + "ABC")
```

Comment: Dont use `+` for string concatenation! Use an f-string or `.format()`.

Answer (score 0):

The "+" symbol is used to concatenate two strings together. In your code 9 is and integer and "ABC" is a string, in order for the code to work, both items need to be strings, which means that you need to change `print(9+"ABC")` to `print(str(9)+"ABC")`

Comment: Thank you for answering and clearing my doubts

Answer (score 0):

`+` operator can be used with same type of objects. In your case you are trying to add an Integer with a strings, which is a type mismatch.
In case you want to concatenate it as strings change `9` to String as in following statement:

`print(str(9)+"ABC")`

**To answer why `print(9, "ABC")` is working ?**

This is working because `print()` supports VLA (Variable length argument) and its considering `9` as a integer input where as `"ABC"` as a String Input.