# Having issues with turning integers to strings and then concatenating

Tags: python

I have an integer called score, I turn it into a string and then try to get python to print a string of score plus a few other strings

```
score = 0
str(score)
variable = (" you have" + score + "points")
print(variable)
```

However it just tells me that score is still an integer, how do I fix this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects

Answer (score 3):

Strings and numbers are immutable, so `str` and `int` don't change the underlying value, but instead return a ***new*** value that you have to use.

For example:

```
score = 0
score = str(score)
variable = " you have " + score + " points"
print(variable)
```

or

```
score = 0
variable = " you have " + str(score) + " points"
print(variable)
```

However, using f-strings is probably better in this situation:

```
score = 0
variable = f" you have {score} points"
print(variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all python is case-sensitive you need to change the names. And then you are doing all conversion and casting in memory because strings are immutable, and values don't change unless they are re-assigned so assign it like this:

```
Score = 0
Score = str(Score)
Variable = "you have " +Score + " points"
print(Variable)
```

Output:

```
you have 0 points
```