# How to make what I print into a variable?

Tags: python

I'm making a timer and I got it to tick down, and display properly in the command prompt with this:

```
min = (code for counting minutes)
sec = (code for counting seconds)

print( min , ":" , sec , sep="" )
```

```
12:34
```

Now I want to make what is printed in to a variable/string so I could use it in other code.
Btw I don't need for the time to display the time in `cmd`, I just need to make min:sec in to a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Comment: Are you using classes? if you aren't then place the `min` and `sec` outside of your `definitions`

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you'll also want to format the time with leading zeros, i.e. `03:04` instead of `3:4`. The simplest way is using the f-strings:

```
v = f'{min:02}:{sec:02}'
```

For pre-3.6, you can use `str.format()` instead:

```
v = '{:02}:{02}'.format(min, sec)
```