# Automatic reading of the next cell with openpyxl

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, openpyxl

I created a looped program (with selenium chromedriver), which on each restart should read me in the next cell. unfortunately I can't. I had tried the following solution, unfortunately the following error obviously appears:

"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

to summarize it is only part of the code:

```
while

number=1

sh1=wb['Example']
sheet=sh1["A"+ number].value  #sheet A1 not work
print(sheet)

number +=1
```

Ay intent is to read after each reopening of the program:
the first time in cell A1,
the second time in cell A2 and so on...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it: you have to cast `number` as a string.

So adding `sheet=sh1["A"+ str(number)].value` should do.