# BeautifulSoup soup.find with a variable loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This code works:

```
    try:
        summary = section.find('p', {'data-testid': 'vuln-summary-0'})
        summary = summary.text
    except AttributeError:
        summary = 'N/A'
    #print (summary)
```

What I am trying to do is put this in a loop like:

```
y = 0
while y < 3:

    try:
        summary = section.find('p', {'data-testid': 'vuln-summary-'+y})
        summary = summary.text
    except AttributeError:
        summary = 'N/A'
    y = y +1
```

I am hoping to get the code to loop through to get vuln-summary-0, vuln-summary-1 and vuln-summary-2.

Thank you.

Comment: What error are you receiving? Also, you may be able to use find_all rather than find.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the y to a string and that should give you what you are looking for:

```
{'data-testid': 'vuln-summary-'+ str(y)}
```