# Not able to print a "str" with a sum of two "int"s

Tags: python

So im trying to to add two int variables and printing it with a str but it doesnt seem to work

```
x = 10
y = 20
apple = "Number of apples "

sentence = apple +(x+y)
print(sentence)
```

Comment: `apple` is a string.  `x` and `y` are integers.  Python does not allow you to add these data types using the `+` symbol.

Comment: Did you mean `sentence = apple + str(x+y)`?

Comment: But you can print them as separate arguments: `print(apple, x+y)`

Comment: Use a f-string! `print(f'Number of apples {x+y}')`, or `print(f'{apple} {x+y}')` if you really need the intermediate variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Answer (score 4):

The code failed because you are trying to concatenate a string with an integer. Try to replace the 4th statement with the following:

```py
sentence = apple + str(x+y)
```

The "str" function will convert the x+y expression result into a string, then the concatenation will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `sentence = apple + str(x+y)`, `print(f'{apple} {x+y}')`, or `print('{}{}'.format(apple, x+y)`