# Keep getting TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str on my code

Tags: python

I searched for other answers but couldn't get it right. It'd be awesome if someone could help me :) I keep getting this error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str | on this code. I was trying to write a code that makes automatic e-mail based on the name of the person plus the ammount of characters in their name.

```
name = input("whats your name?")

number_of_letters = len(name+ "gmail.com")

print(len(name))

print((name) + (len(name)) + ("@gmail.com"))
```

Comment: Which line? I suspect this isn't your actual code, and you are actually doing something like `print(...) + len(...)`.

Comment: As for the error in the title, you can't add `name + len(name)`, either; you'd have to convert the `int` that `len` returns back to a `str` first: `name + str(len(name))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `int` and `str`,

You just need to change this line,

```
print((name) + str(len(name)) + ("@gmail.com"))
#              ^ edited here
```

Answer (score 0):

`len(name)` returns an int value, so when you do `name + len(name)`, Python doesn't know if it should be adding the values or concatenating them.  You can use `str(len(name))` to make it clear that you want `len(name)` to be treated as a string.  Also, the parentheses around each piece aren't necessary (although they won't cause any problems either).

```
print(name + str(len(name)) + "@gmail.com")
```