# How do I send strings and a variable through a discord webhook description?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, webhooks

I'm trying to send a value and a text message through a discord webhook message, but I can't get it to work.

```
value = 10
embed = DiscordEmbed(title="boxing tracker", description="boxing wins for lwlwlwlwlwlwlw: " + value, color="03b2f8")
```

I want the output of the description to be `boxing wins for lwlwlwlwlwlwlw: 10`.
I've tried different methods such as using `[value]` and a comma between the value and the string, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a solution.
Before sending the value I have to make the value a string.

Ex.

```
value = 69

value1=str(value)
```