# Converting/concatenating integer to strying with python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to read the last line from a text file. Each line starts with a number, so the next time something is inserted, the new number will be incremented by 1.

For example, this would be a typical file

```
1. Something here          date
2. Something else here     date
#next entry would be  "3.   something    date"
```

If the file is blank I can enter an entry with no problem. However, when there are already entries I get the following error

```
LastItemNum = lineList[-1][0:1] +1 #finds the last item's number
TypeError: cannon concatenate 'str' and 'int objects
```

Here's my code for the function

```
 def AddToDo(self): 
    FILE = open(ToDo.filename,"a+") #open file for appending and reading
    FileLines = FILE.readlines() #read the lines in the file
    if os.path.getsize("EnteredInfo.dat") == 0: #if there is nothing, set the number to 1
        LastItemNum = "1"
    else:
        LastItemNum = FileLines[-1][0:1] + 1 #finds the last items number
    FILE.writelines(LastItemNum + ". " + self.Info + "       " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + '\n')
    FILE.close()
```

I tried to convert LastItemNum to a string but I get the same "cannot concatenate" error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a string out of a string and an integer in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823211/making-a-string-out-of-a-string-and-an-integer-in-python)

Comment: @HansEngel: That's the opposite problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LastItemNum = int(lineList[-1][0:1]) +1
```

then you've to convert `LastItemNum` back to string before writing to file, using :

`LastItemNum=str(LastItemNum)` or instead of this you can use string formatting.

Comment: use `str(LastItemNum)`  inside `writelines()`, because `LastItemNum` is a `int`.