# Python 2.7 and Flask - using functions from "Random" module returns "500 Internal Server Error" when using venv

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, flask, python-venv

I'm testing a web service written with python and flask. Within that service I want to generate a random number. None of the solutions posted on the web seem to work, **as if the "random" module does not work.** I checked, and there's no random.py or random.pyc within the folders around the webservice.py

Here's how I start the web service:

```
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ python webservice.py
```

**How can I fix random module not being available when running in a virtual environment?**

```
import random
from random import randint

x = random.random()*100
x = randint(0,10)
print 'r' + x #does not work
```

Here's what's in the venv folder:

[image]

Comment: *as if the "random" module does not work* ?? what is the exact error you get ? If you do not get any error, what is the behavior you see ?

Comment: One more thing : change the local variable names from `random = ...` to something else.

Comment: I tried multiple local variable names, started with x, but nothing worked

Comment: gonna need more info than this. What does "not work" mean? Does it print `r` to the console or does it provide some kind of traceback?

Comment: You dont have to try multiple variable name. just `x` should do. And what is "does not work". If we were to start guessing, your problem might end up being something else altogether.

Comment: By does not work I mean that the web service returns 500 Internal Server Error when processing the call to the random function. I don't know how to debug it further than that, but every call to functions from Random that I made ended up crashing the web service

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the help("random") method will give a list.

- Then reinstall the module in that venv. Also what is in the lib folder?

a link to help.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: print help("random") actually prints help when used from Python. FILE
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py

Comment: lib contains frameworks for Flask, flup, pip, parse_rest, werkezeug, jinja and some other .py files. Should I try to use something like pip random?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you try to add string and integer.

[Making a string out of a string and an integer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823211/making-a-string-out-of-a-string-and-an-integer-in-python)

```
print 'x' + str(randint(0,10)) # try casting the int to string :)
```