# How to add a number into a site on python

Tags: python, web

I need to add a number into a site which is then processes in python:

```
text = "4122822"
get = 'http://example.com/api/jobs/text/'
```

I want text to go where I wrote it inside the link.
Is there a way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean simple string interpolation ? It can be done by
`get = "http://example.com/api/jobs/" + text + "/"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a string out of a string and an integer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823211/making-a-string-out-of-a-string-and-an-integer-in-python). See also: [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects). Also, since `text` is already a string: [Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append it like below :

```
text = "4122822"
get = 'http://example.com/api/jobs/'+text +'/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python3:

```
get = f'http://example.com/api/jobs/{text}/'
```

Python2:

```
get = 'http://example.com/api/jobs/{}/'.format(text)
```